# Скрипт tampermonkey запускается только после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Скрипт запускается не сразу , а только после обновление страницы например через F5. Он отвечает за освещение (которое профессиональное) в роликах и за качество самого видео на youtube . Не могу понять какой конкретно параметр я забыл указать или может быть настройку. Сам скрипт работает в расширении tampermonkey

глянуть код https://pastebin.com/UewzubNZ

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что найдутся желающие разбираться в коде на полтысячи строк...

Comment: Может стоит заменить `document-start` на `document-idle`?

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)